# UI not updating on bool update

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a rectangle where its visibiltiy is bound to a bool and has a `BoolToVis` converter. This is what it looks like in `XAML`:

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="#FE7200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="5" Visibility="{Binding LocationsClicked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

I have a get/set for the bool:

```
private bool _locationsClicked;
public bool LocationsClicked
{
    get => _locationsClicked;
    set
    {
        if (_locationsClicked == value) return;
        _locationsClicked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LocationsClicked));
    }
}
```

I then have a `DelegateCommand` that is bound to a button, that I want to set the visibility of the rectangle to true:

```
public DelegateCommand NavigateToLocationsCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new DelegateCommand(param =>
        {
            LocationsClicked = true;
        });
    }
}
```

Through the debugger I follow this through, `LocationsClicked` is set to true but the rectangle is not made visible. I've tried changing the mode, and what is strange is that if I set:

```
private bool _locationsClicked;
```

to

```
private bool _locationsClicked = true;
```

the rectangle is visible on startup. Where am I going wrong in that the command is not setting updating the UI?

This is what my converter looks like:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

The ViewModel in question inherits from `BaseViewModel` (this is the entire class):

```
internal class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The entire ViewModel:

```
internal class DashboardViewModel : BaseViewModel
{ 
    private object _selectedViewModel;

    private bool _jobsClicked = true;
    private bool _locationsClicked;
    private bool _clientsClicked;
    private bool _usersClicked;

    public DashboardViewModel()
    {
        SelectedViewModel = new JobsViewModel();
    }

    #region Get/Set
    public object SelectedViewModel
    {
        get => _selectedViewModel;
        set
        {
            if (_selectedViewModel == value) return;
            _selectedViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedViewModel));
        }
    }

    public bool JobsClicked
    {
        get => _jobsClicked;
        set
        {
            if (_jobsClicked == value) return;
            _jobsClicked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(JobsClicked));
        }
    }

    public bool LocationsClicked
    {
        get => _locationsClicked;
        set
        {
            if (_locationsClicked == value) return;
            _locationsClicked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LocationsClicked));
        }
    }

    public bool ClientsClicked
    {
        get => _clientsClicked;
        set
        {
            if (_clientsClicked == value) return;
            _clientsClicked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ClientsClicked));
        }
    }

    public bool UsersClicked
    {
        get => _usersClicked;
        set
        {
            if (_usersClicked == value) return;
            _usersClicked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UsersClicked));
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private void ResetVisibility()
    {
        JobsClicked = false;
        LocationsClicked = true;
        ClientsClicked = false;
        UsersClicked = false;
    }

    #region Navigation
    public DelegateCommand NavigateToJobsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(param =>
            {
                SelectedViewModel = new JobsViewModel();
                ResetVisibility();
                JobsClicked = true;
            });
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand NavigateToLocationsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(param =>
            {
                SelectedViewModel = new LocationsViewModel();
                ResetVisibility();
                LocationsClicked = true;
            });
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand NavigateToClientsCommmand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(param =>
            {
                SelectedViewModel = new ClientsViewModel();
                ResetVisibility();
                ClientsClicked = true;
            });
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand NavigateToEmployeesCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand(param =>
            {
                SelectedViewModel = new UsersViewModel();
                ResetVisibility();
                UsersClicked = true;
            });
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Can you post your converter? I want to see the class BooleanToVisibilityConverter if you have properly configured or not.

Comment: @MilanG Sure, I just updated the question.

Comment: How is your binding context connected to your xaml?

Comment: It's just a UserControl with a ViewModel attached to it, there are other bindings (not bools) that work without issue.

Comment: Is the `Mode=TwoWay` necessary here?

Comment: @Stefan That was the latest version of my code, I have tried oneway and twoway and still no luck!

Comment: One final thing; have you set the breakpoint at the actual `LocationsClicked = true;` line? I placed one myself at the `return new DelegateCommand(param =>` line, it fired at a different moment.

Comment: @Stefan Hmm if I set the breakpoint on that line, it doesn't actually step into the setter.. should I expect it to?

Comment: @mm8 Sure, I've updated the question

Comment: You still haven't included the view model class where the LocationsClicked property is defined. Your issue is not reproducible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mm8 Sorry I misunderstood you before, my `ViewModel` is pretty beefy but I've included a version in my question now.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce your issue with this version?

Comment: Are you sure that both the command target and the rectangle bind to the **same** view-model instance? Using the debugger, set the break points to the command handler and to the property getter, and use the *Make object ID* context menu item in the *Locals* window to ensure both instances are same.

Comment: It works for me provided that a set a Height for the Rectangle. A Rectangle width a height of 0 is always invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the issue, turns out this style that I have on the `Button` for `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` is somehow covering the Rectangle. Here is the style and I will have to rethink this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation To="#FE7200" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <ColorAnimation To="#FF222226" 
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd" 
                            Duration="0:0:0.25"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```